# Flutter IOS - fetching API in background when app is closed

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, background, background-service

Is there a good way to run code in the background (fetching api and calculating something) on IOS? I can't find a solution that works reliably.

I already used flutter_background_service but after some time it stopped working on the IOS simulator.

Comment: iOS doesn't have a long running background task, see more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing_background_strategies_for_your_app.